# regex that won't find pattern in alt text for php eregi_replace

Tags: php, regex

I'm wondering what the regex for an eregi_replace would be needed to catch a string that is not contained in an alt attribute.

e.g. It should find and replace John Doe in:

"John Doe was born on..."

but not find/replace when John Doe's in any tag for example:

```
<img src="/jd.jpg" alt="John Doe at the beach" />
```

Comment: Does it have to be `eregi_replace`?  The `ereg[i]_` functions are deprecated in favor of the much more powerful `preg_` functions.  With `preg_replace` it might be possible.

Comment: sure...I'll go with whatever tool can get the job done. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I wanted to replace "John Doe" if it's not inside a tag, I would do this:

```
$str = preg_replace('/John Doe(?![^<>]*+>)/i', $new_name, $str);
```

`(?![^<>]*+>)` is a negative lookahead; it says "if there are any angle brackets ahead of this point, the first one is not a closing bracket."  That's not foolproof, since attribute values can contain angle brackets, but in my experience they rarely do.

Regexes are fundamentally incompatible with HTML; even with the advanced features offered by the `preg_` suite, like [lookarounds](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) and [possessive quantifiers](http://www.regular-expressions.info/possessive.html), you often have to rely on simplifying assumptions like *no angle brackets in attribute values*.  I wouldn't even attempt this job with the much-more-limited `ereg_` functions.

Comment: Neat usage of zero-width lookahead.

Answer (score 0):

You've reached the limitations of regex. You'll need a custom parser for this.
tags can be nested, and regex can't match patterns like

```
<b>
<<b>>
<<<b>>>
```

while not matching patterns like

```
<b>>
<<b>
<<b>>>
```

etc

Comment: But if we're searching for text in an element there wouldn't be nesting. An element is within <...>